# Why can't I get a loop to spin for less than a millisecond in C++ on Windows with Chrono?

Tags: c++, windows, c++-chrono

EDIT: I am using VS2013 and on Windows 7.

With the below code I'd expect to be able to have a time difference of at least one microsecond, however, when executed it builds it up to at least 1000 microseconds (one millisecond). What is the reasoning I'm not able to get a time lower then one millisecond? Is there any way around this?

```
// SleepTesting.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <chrono>
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILETIME startFileTime, endFileTime;
    uint64_t ullStartTime, ullEndTime;
    bool sleep = true;
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(now - start);

    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&startFileTime);
    ullStartTime = static_cast<uint64_t>(startFileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32 | startFileTime.dwLowDateTime;

    while (sleep)
    {
        now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast < std::chrono::microseconds > (now - start);
        if (elapsedTime.count() > 0)
        {
            sleep = false;
        }
    }

    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&endFileTime);
    ullEndTime = static_cast<uint64_t>(endFileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32 | endFileTime.dwLowDateTime;
    uint64_t timeDifferenceHundredsOfNano = ullEndTime - ullStartTime;

    std::cout << "Elapsed time with Chrono library: " << elapsedTime.count() << " micro-seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time with Windows.h FILETIME: " << timeDifferenceHundredsOfNano << " hundreds of nanoseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @VTT That question doesn't address this question asking about the chrono library.

Comment: Might be a limitation on the system's ability to sleep. Windows probably has a minimum possible sleep time. You might want to look into Windows high resolution timers.

Comment: @cppguy My understanding is that chrono is the Window's high resolution timer.

Comment: Using VS2017 on Windows 10 I get 1 micro-second.

Comment: @BoPersson Good to know. I should have stated in the question detail I'm on Windows 7 and using VS2013. I'm going to have to retry this with some updates when I get a chance.

Comment: You are confusing *accuracy* and *precision*. While you get microsecond precision in the data type, accuracy is dependent on the tick interval, as [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Clock).

Answer (score 0):

since you're using system_clock, I think that you can't get micro-second resolution on windows 7 (at least from what I've seen).
try high-resolution clock, but even that won't always work, since windows doesn't even guarantee that time elapsed between two consecutive operations is less then one millisecond, even without sleeping

Answer (score 0):

IIRC in VS2013 the system_clock (and highres_clock) are in clock ticks i.e. ms. If you need higher resolution you can go all Windows and take a look at [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
LARGE_INTEGER startCount;
LARGE_INTEGER endCount;
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCount);
{...}
QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCount);

double startTimeInMicroSec = startCount.QuadPart * (1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);
double endTimeInMicroSec = endCount.QuadPart * (1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);

// endTimeInMicroSec - startTimeInMicroSec
```

disclaimer: ocular compilation